# How to make orthogonal edges using Cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

How to make orthogonal edges with [Cytoscape.js](https://github.com/cytoscape)?

I have seen [this Github issue](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/359), but didn't get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the segments style feature mentioned/developed in the issue: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/segments-edges

There's a demo of all edge types you can reference as well: http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/18504640d9a03c178fff/